# PyBind - Python to C++ interface

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

It makes sense that using PyBind to interface and call C++ code from Python will make the Python code much faster, but does that hold true for **Python code being called from C++**?

In other words, does PyBind only provide the interface and not the performance gain like Cython does when calling **Python code from C++**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, code with pybind is NOT always faster than python, it depends on use case([example](https://github.com/pybind/pybind11/issues/1227)). Binding has overhead and it might take away all performance gain from calling native C++ code.

No magic happens when you call python code from С++. Same amount of work needs to be done in both cases by same machinery.